# capistrano deploy from one local directory to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I want to deploy application on my local machine. For example I have my Rails APP in:
`/home/thesis/dev/myapp` but I want to `cap deploy:setup` to `/home/thesis/deploy/`. I have tried that but capistrano tries to connect to `localhost`, but it is not needed at all. How can I solve it?

Here goes my deploy.rb

```
role :app, "localhost"
role :web, "localhost"
role :db,  "localhost", :primary => true

set(:deploy_to) { "/home/thesis/dev/myapp" }
set :bundle_without,  [:development, :test]
set :use_sudo, false

set :repository, "."
set :scm, :none
set :deploy_via, :copy

set :copy_dir, "/home/thesis/deploy/tmp"
set :copy_remote_dir, "/home/thesis/deploy/tmp"
```

It drops with:

```
connection failed for: localhost (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `localhost` issue is because you're setting this in the `role` definitions.  Since you're doing all this locally, and since Capistrano requires a role, you can set the following:

```
role :app, ""
```

I also think you're setting the `copy_dir` and `copy_remote_dir` values incorrectly.  I'd recommend removing these and letting Capistrano use it's defaults.

Here's a full config which should work for you:

```
role :app, ""

set :use_sudo, false
set :application, 'thesis'     # you'll need to specify an app name
set :repository, "."
set :scm, :none
set :deploy_to, "/home/thesis/deploy/"   # the destination dir
set :deploy_via, :copy

# override deploy:restart since this isn't a Rails app
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    # no-op
  end
end
```

Comment: This shouldn't work, because the `:deploy_code` task uses SSH to connect. Connecting to "" will throw an exception.

Comment: @Jani off the top of my head - punt by setting up SSHD locally, etc.

Comment: did this work without going through ssh? @BryanH has a good point, but this answer is marked as accepted.

Comment: It doesn't work, as it still tries to connect to local host via SSH. The solution would be to setup a local SSH server as @BryanH suggested.

Comment: The issue is ssh server is not configured. 
Below answer by @Bruno Peres is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're missing a SSH server to connect on your on machine because you only have the client installed.

Test `ssh 127.0.0.1`, if you still get a connection refuse error, use:

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

To install the ssh server.

Answer (score 1):

I also get this problem, for I had set SSH port to 13000, not the default port 22. 
And the /etc/hosts.deny added

```
sshd:ALL
```

/etc/hosts.allow added

```
sshd:#some allowed IPs
```

I processing are:

1) add to deploy.rb

```
ssh_options[:port] = 13600
```

2) add localhost to hosts.allow

```
sshed:127.0.0.1 localhost # others allowed IPs
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an ssh server installed for local deployment to work, such as openssh (`sudo apt-get install openssh-server` to install)

*config/deploy/staging.rb*

```
set :stage, :staging

role :app, %w{127.0.0.1}
role :web, %w{127.0.0.1}
role :db,  %w{127.0.0.1}

server '127.0.0.1', user: 'your-username', roles: %w{web app}
set :branch, "staging"
```

*config/deploy.rb*

```
set :deploy_to ,'/home/your/app/path/deploy'
# Path of tests to be run, use array with empty string to run all tests
set :tests, ['']

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Runs test before deploying, can't deploy unless they pass"
  task :run_tests do
    test_log = "log/capistrano.test.log"
    tests = fetch(:tests)
    tests.each do |test|
      puts "--> Running tests: '#{test}', please wait ..."
      unless system "bundle exec rspec #{test} > #{test_log} 2>&1"
        puts "--> Aborting deployment! One or more tests in '#{test}' failed. Results in: #{test_log}"
        exit;
      end
      puts "--> '#{test}' passed"
    end
    puts "--> All tests passed, continuing deployment"
    system "rm #{test_log}"
  end

  # Only allow a deploy with passing tests to be deployed
  before :deploy, "deploy:run_tests"
end
```

Run it with with

```
cap staging deploy
```